# Firebase Overwrite

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here is my code.

```
    set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            final FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            String emails = user.getEmail().toString().trim();
            String titless = mtitle.getText().toString().trim();
            String pricess = mprice.getText().toString();
            String timess = mtime.getText().toString();
            String productss = mproduct.getText().toString();
            String detailss = mdetail.getText().toString();
            String categorys = mspinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

            final ContactsInfo contact = new ContactsInfo(emails,titless,pricess,timess,productss,detailss,categorys);
            mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        i = (int) dataSnapshot.child("商品").getChildrenCount();


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            mRef.child("商品").child(String.valueOf(i)).setValue(contact);

        }
    });
}}
```

When I use this code to write into my firebase,it will overwrite number0's data,after that it will work normally, I want to know how should I do if I don't want it to overwrite my previous data.

Answer (score 1):

The `onDataChange` function code is executed at a later point of time than `setValue`. The `onDataChange` function is called asynchronously. Try the following code -

```
set.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                final FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                String emails = user.getEmail().toString().trim();
                String titless = mtitle.getText().toString().trim();
                String pricess = mprice.getText().toString();
                String timess = mtime.getText().toString();
                String productss = mproduct.getText().toString();
                String detailss = mdetail.getText().toString();
                String categorys = mspinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                final ContactsInfo contact = new ContactsInfo(emails, titless, pricess, timess, productss, detailss, categorys);
                mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    i = (int) dataSnapshot.child("商品").getChildrenCount();
                    mRef.child("商品").child(String.valueOf(i)).setValue(contact);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I write like your code, and it keeps write in the same data and never stops.

Comment: Oh, because the `setValue` triggers the `onDataChange` again. Have a flag to execute `setValue` only once / don't execute `setValue` if the value is already set.

Comment: Either have a flag to execute setValue only once or don't execute setValue if the desired value is already set.